# Accessing a class method from within an Active Record scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am having issues with the scope in this model and I'm at a loss at how best to fix it. I would like to call the `distinct_mechanics_sql` from within the scope to keep things cleaner, but when I run this I get an "undefined local variable or method" error. Here is the model:

```
class Mechanics < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_moz, -> { joins("JOIN (#{distinct_mechanics_sql}) mh ON mh.mechanic_id = mechanics.id") }

  def distinct_mechanics_sql 
    """
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (mechanic_id) *
    FROM checkups
    ORDER BY mechanic_id, updated_at DESC
    """
  end

end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scopes are same as class methods, so within the scope you are implicitly call another class methods. And your `distinct_mechanics_sql` is an instance method, to use it inside a scope declare it as:

```
def self.distinct_mechanics_sql
```

or

```
def Mechanics.distinct_mechanics_sql
```

or

```
class << self 
  def distinct_mechanics_sql
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great! Since it's just a string that I'm inserting into the scope call, is there a better way to do this? Store it as a class constant maybe? What would you recommend with something like this?

Comment: I would not recommend you to use scopes at all, as well as pure sql. You should do your best with ORM. For now, I would recommend you to move all this stuff to a single class method. Then, if you are unable to change code from pure SQL to AR calls, you can show your relations and working class method to community([codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)) for improvements.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about codereview, I will use it.